# How do we import intents, entities, etc. from Excel to Watson Asssitant?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

we'd like to import an excel into watson assistant(intents, entities, dialog) instead of building a chatbot from workspace, we do know others have a tool to do it, we'd like to build similar one, any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding what @data_henrik said, to import entities and intents you need separate files and these steps:

1. Collect the intents and examples into a CSV file, or export them from another workspace (if you want. The required format is as follows:

   example,intent

So it can be:

```
I'd like to request one product, requestProduct
```

So, if you want add more examples, you need add more lines:

```
I wanna request one product from your company, requestProduct
Can I request something with this chat?, requestProduct
```

2. After save your file, go to Watson Assistant, click on the Import Icon, choose your Intents/Entities (separated file) *CSV* file, and the system begins to train itself on the new data, after some time, done! You can check the imported intents and examples in the Intents tab, if not, just reload your page.

Obs: For use *CSV* file, you can click on the menu from Excel -> Save As -> and choose *CSV* `(.csv)` format.

Obs II: The maximum CSV file size is 10MB. If is larger than it, consider splitting it into multiple files and importing them separately.

- See more about import Intents [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/intents.html#defining-intents) (Importing intents and examples).
- See more about import Entities [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#defining-entities) (Importing entities).

Comment: Another important thing, be sure to configure those files to UTF-8 encoding when exporting and importing while working with Microsoft Excel. Watson Assistant accepts only UTF-8 and thats not the default for Microsoft Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You can import intents and entities to Watson Assistant. The format of the CSV (comma-separated values) file is documented for [intents](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/intents.html#importing-intents-and-examples) and for [entities](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#importing-entities). You need separate files.

You could also read a CSV or Excel spreadsheet with a tool and make programmtic calls via the [API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/curl.html?curl) to define intents, entities and more. [A longer time ago I wrote a command line tool to import and export workspaces](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool). The related [SDKs for the Watson services are here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/).